# there is no any change to the rows displayed when doing "search" in yii2

Tags: php, web, yii2

I have problem when making modelsearch in yii2. Here's is relation diagram

[image]

I want to display **Jurusan** from table **aitambah** to table **ais3** and I want to display **NamaMahasiswa** from table **ai** to **ais3**. I made table **s3penghubung** so that table **aitambah** can be related to **ais3**. I was able to display them. But, when I try to type "BIO" in **Jurusan** field, the searching not working properly. it is refreshing the page. there is no any change to the rows displayed. so, what should I do to fix that? 
[image]

**MODEL SEARCH CODE**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Ais3;
use app\models\AiTambah;

/**
 * Ais3Search represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\Ais3`.
 */
class Ais3Search extends Ais3
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'kode'], 'integer'],
            [['NRP', 'NRP1', 'NRP2', 'NRP3', 'NRP4', 'NRP5', 'NRP6', 'NRP7', 'namaMahasiswaText', 'ProgramStudi', 'TanggalMasuk', 'TanggalKeluar', 'jURUSANText','NAMKANTOR','ANGKATAN'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public $NamaMahasiswa;
    public $namaMahasiswaText;
    public $NRP1;
    public $NRP2;
    public $NRP3;
    public $NRP4;
    public $NRP5;
    public $NRP6;
    public $NRP7;
    public $JURUSAN;
    public $jURUSANText;
    public $NAMKANTOR;
    public $ANGKATAN;





    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Ais3::find();
        $query->joinWith('ai');

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'kode' => $this->kode,

        ]);




        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ais3.NRP', $this->NRP])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ai.NamaMahasiswa', $this->namaMahasiswaText])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ais3.ProgramStudi', $this->ProgramStudi])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ai.TanggalMasuk', $this->TanggalMasuk])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ais3.TanggalKeluar', $this->TanggalKeluar])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'aitambah.JURUSAN', $this->JURUSAN]);



        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

**MY GRIDVIEW CODE**

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'id',
            'NRP',
            'namaMahasiswaText',
            'ProgramStudi',
            //'TanggalMasuk',
            [
            'attribute' => 'TanggalMasuk',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->ai->TanggalMasuk;
            },],
            'TanggalKeluar',

            //YANG DITAMBAH
            /*[
                'attribute'=>'NRP1',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.JURUSAN',
                'label' => 'Jurusan',
            ],*/

            'jURUSANText',

            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP2',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.NAMKANTOR',
                'label' => 'Nama Kantor',
            ],
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP3',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.ANGKATAN',
                'label' => 'Angkatan',
            ],
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP4',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.TELP',
                'label' => 'Nomor HP/Telp',
            ],
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP5',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.PEKERJAAN',
                'label' => 'Pekejaan',
            ],
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP6',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.EMAIL',
                'label' => 'Email',
            ],
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP7',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.KODEPROP',
                'label' => 'KodeProp',
            ],


            // 'kode',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

**MY MODEL'S CODE**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "ais3".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $NRP
 * @property string $ProgramStudi
 * @property string $TanggalMasuk
 * @property string $TanggalKeluar
 * @property integer $kode
 *
 * @property Ai $nRP
 * @property S3penghubung $kode0
 */
class Ais3 extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'ais3';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['kode'], 'required'],
            [['kode'], 'integer'],
            [['NRP'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['ProgramStudi'], 'string', 'max' => 5],
            [['TanggalMasuk', 'TanggalKeluar'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['NRP'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Ai::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['NRP' => 'NRP']],
            [['kode'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => S3penghubung::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['kode' => 'kode']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'NRP' => Yii::t('app', 'Nrp'),
            'ProgramStudi' => Yii::t('app', 'Program Studi'),
            'TanggalMasuk' => Yii::t('app', 'Tanggal Masuk'),
            'TanggalKeluar' => Yii::t('app', 'Tanggal Keluar'),
            'kode' => Yii::t('app', 'Kode'),
            'namaMahasiswaText' => Yii::t('app', 'Nama Mahasiswa'),
            'jURUSANText' => Yii::t('app', 'Jurusan'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getai()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Ai::className(), ['NRP' => 'NRP']);
    }



    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getS3penghubung()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(S3penghubung::className(), ['kode' => 'kode']);
    }

    //YANG DITAMBAH
    public function getRelasiS3()
    {
        return array(
                'aitambah'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Aitambah', 'S3Penghubung(AiS3.id, Aitambah.NRP)'),
            );
    }


    public function getNamaMahasiswaText()
    {
        $ai = ai::findOne(['NRP'=> $this->NRP]);
        if (empty($ai))
            return '';
        return $ai->NamaMahasiswa;
    }

    public function getJURUSANText()
    {
        $aitambah = aitambah::findOne(['NRP'=> $this->NRP]);
        if (empty($aitambah))
            return '';
        return $aitambah->JURUSAN;
    }

}
```

I dont know how to fix those codes. Could you please help me to solve this? Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very difficult to debug. Try to keep a consistency for your naming conventions. The Yii way is all lower case letters separated with underscores.

Please read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/) and [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/) about displaying and sorting relations.

As for the solution you can experiment a bit with the following:

---

Create a new relation in your model:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getAitambah()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Aitambah::className(), ['NRP' => 'NRP']);
}
```

Then in your `SearchModel`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'kode'], 'integer'],
        [['NRP', 'NRP1', 'NRP2', 'NRP3', 'NRP4', 'NRP5', 'NRP6', 'NRP7', 'namaMahasiswaText', 'ProgramStudi', 'TanggalMasuk', 'TanggalKeluar', 'jURUSANText','NAMKANTOR','ANGKATAN', 'JURUSAN'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

And in your search method:

```
...
$query = Ais3::find();
query->joinWith(['ai ai', 'aitambah aitambah']);
...
```

Finally in your view:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'JURUSAN',
    'value' => 'aitambah.JURUSAN',
    'label' => 'JURUSAN',
],
```

Comment: thankyou so much Kostas Mitsarakis. It works. God Bless You O:)

Comment: Really? Great! To tell the truth it was a wild guess because I couldn't understand much of your code. Also if you want mark the answer as the accepted one.